# CMake (Android Toolchain) - Error running link command: No such file or directory

Tags: android, c++, linux, cmake, toolchain

I am using CMake for building the Android project.
“android.toolchain.cmake” toolchain is used for building the project.

All the environment variables are set as described in the usage part of the android cmake.
Following Option variables are set as environment variables
ANDTOOLCHAIN
ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN
ANDROID_ABI
ANDROID_NATIVE_API
ANDROID_STL
CC and CXX to point to the androideabi-gcc & androideabi-g++ respectively

CMAKE is successfully generating the Make files but when I “make” the project its throwing “Error running link command: No such file or directory”.

The details of the link.txt are as under

> *cd /Extra/svnroot/2014_Project/build/project123 && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/project123dir/link.txt --verbose=1
>
> **CMAKE_C_COMPILER** -fPIC -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/path_to_sysroot_dir/sysroot -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-deprecated -Wno-unused -Wno-unused-variable -Wsign-compare -Wsequence-point -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-strict-aliasing -pthread  -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -shared -Wl,-soname,libproject123.so -o ../libproject123.so  CMakeFiles/project123_Sources.dir/MyAdapter.cpp.o
>   CMakeFiles/ project123_Sources.dir /SystemInfo.cpp.o CMakeFiles/
>   project123_Sources.dir /ServiceControl.cpp.o  CMakeFiles/
>   project123_Sources.dir /Wrapper.cpp.o  CMakeFiles/
>   project123_Sources.dir /Service.cpp.o  CMakeFiles/
>   project123_Sources.dir /MemMap.cpp.o  CMakeFiles/
>   project123_Sources.dir.dir/Trace.cpp.o
>   -L/path_to_ toolchain_dir/android-toolchain/bin/armeabi-v7a 
>   -L/Extra/svnroot/2014_Q4_Mobile/build
>   -L/path_to_thirdparty_lib/zlib-1.2.7/lib
>   -L/path_to_thirdparty_lib /libzip-0.11.1
>   -L/path_to_thirdparty_lib /boost_1_53_0/lib-android
>   -L/path_to_thirdparty_lib/curl-7.26.0-patch/lib 
>   -L/path_to_thirdparty_lib /fips-openssl-1.0.1g/lib  /path_to_thirdparty_lib
>   /boost_1_53_0/lib-android/libboost_date_time-gcc-mt-1_53.a 
>   /path_to_thirdparty_lib/boost_1_53_0/lib-android/libboost_filesystem-gcc-mt-1_53.a
>   /path_to_thirdparty_lib/boost_1_53_0/lib-android/libboost_system-gcc-mt-1_53.a  /path_to_thirdparty_lib
>   /boost_1_53_0/lib-android/libboost_thread-gcc-mt-1_53.a
>   /path_to_thirdparty_lib
>   /boost_1_53_0/lib-android/libboost_program_options-gcc-mt-1_53.a
>   /path_to_thirdparty_lib
>   /boost_1_53_0/lib-android/libboost_serialization-gcc-mt-1_53.a 
>   /path_to_thirdparty_lib /curl-7.26.0-patch/lib/libcurl.a 
>   /path_to_thirdparty_lib /fips-openssl-1.0.1g/lib/libssl.a 
>   /path_to_thirdparty_lib /fips-openssl-1.0.1g/lib/libcrypto.a 
>   /path_to_thirdparty_lib /zlib-1.2.7/lib/libz.a 
>   /path_to_thirdparty_lib /libzip-0.11.1/libzip.a -ldl -lrt 
>   "/path_to_toolchain_dir/android-toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a/thumb/libstdc++.a"
>   "/path_to_toolchain_dir/android-toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a/thumb/libsupc++.a"*

All files in the link.txt file are pointing to the right directory/path and there is no problem with any of the file paths. In the link.txt file instead of using the actual path to the compiler it is using CMAKE_C_COMPILER. I presume this is creating the problem since “make” command is not able to find the actual path to the compiler.

Any help in fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same issue recently, and couldn't figure out why it failed to replace CMAKE_C_COMPILER with the right path. So what I ended up doing is to modify the **android.toolchain.cmake**, where the CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_YYY is being set. From

```
set( CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY "<CMAKE_C_COMPILER> ...")
set( CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_MODULE  "<CMAKE_C_COMPILER> ...")
set( CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE       "<CMAKE_C_COMPILER> ...")
```

to

```
set( CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> ...")
set( CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_MODULE  "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> ...")
set( CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE       "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> ...")
```

And CMake was able to generate the right link.txt. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! You saved the day :)